# How to stop Math.random activity when used with onmousemove?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make `Math.random()` activity stop and not continue anymore when I clicked the button. How can I do that with this code?

```js
var result = document.getElementById('result'); 

  var x =document.getElementById('text');

  var btn = document.querySelector('#btn');


window.onmousemove =function() {
result.innerHTML = Math.random() ;
   }

btn.onclick = function () {
result.innerHTML = "stop" ;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container text-center">
  <div id="text" class="alert alert-danger">JS EGITIMI</div>

<button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-dark">CLICK</button>
   </div>  
    <p id="result" style="margin-top: 100px;margin-bottom: 100px;"></p>
```

Comment: Remove the event: `window.onmousemove = null;`.

Comment: Make a boolean value and set it to false when the button is pressed. In the mousemove event check if that value is set to true before assigning innerHTML

Answer (score 1):

You could just add in a boolean that checks if you can change the value or not.

This way you can turn it on and off by toggling the boolean between `true` and `false`;

```js
var result = document.getElementById('result'); 

var x = document.getElementById('text');

var btn = document.querySelector('#btn');

var canChange = true;

window.onmousemove =function() {
  if(canChange) {
    result.innerHTML = Math.random() ;
  }
}

btn.onclick = function () {
  canChange = false;
  result.innerHTML = "stop";
}
```

```html
<div class="container text-center">
  <div id="text" class="alert alert-danger">JS EGITIMI</div>

  <button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-dark">CLICK</button>
</div>

<p id="result" style="margin-top: 100px;margin-bottom: 100px;"></p>
```

Comment: I get the answer but didn't figure it out why you used canChange to define true? I'm sure it's an easy question but new here tho :

Comment: @Nsur it's just the name i chose for the boolean. A prefix like `is`, `has` or `can` kinda defines that it can only contain 2 states, it's either true (can) or false (cannot). You can choose whatever name you want but such naming conventions just help for readability of the code.

Answer (score 0):

simple reset event on window on button click :

```
btn.onclick = function() {
  result.innerHTML = "stop";
  window.onmousemove = null;
}
```

see snippet

```js
var result = document.getElementById('result');

var x = document.getElementById('text');

var btn = document.querySelector('#btn');


window.onmousemove = function() {
  result.innerHTML = Math.random();
}

btn.onclick = function() {
  result.innerHTML = "stop";
  window.onmousemove = null;
}
```

```html
<div class="container text-center">
  <div id="text" class="alert alert-danger">JS EGITIMI</div>

  <button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-dark">CLICK</button>
</div>
<p id="result" style="margin-top: 100px;margin-bottom: 100px;"></p>
```

Comment: Although I must admit I never checked what browsers do with a no-op handler, better just set it to `null` to ensure it won't fire uselessly. (They may very well avoid entirely the dispatch-event route if there is no registered handler, having just that no-op here may make them work for nothing)

Comment: @Nsur did you fix your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go;

```js
var result = document.getElementById('result'); 

  var x =document.getElementById('text');

  var btn = document.querySelector('#btn');


window.onmousemove =function() {
result.innerHTML = Math.random() ;
   }

btn.onclick = function () {
result.innerHTML = "stop" ;
if(window.onmousemove !== null) {
window.onmousemove = null;
}else {
    window.onmousemove =function() {
        result.innerHTML = Math.random() ;
   }
}
 }
```

```html
<div class="container text-center">
  <div id="text" class="alert alert-danger">JS EGITIMI</div>

<button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-dark">CLICK</button>
   </div>  
    <p id="result" style="margin-top: 100px;margin-bottom: 100px;"></p>
```

Comment: Here i  added the whole functionality to the button i.e, stopping and starting the math.random